# How to get id of tr after clicking its td's element?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a tr column, like this. Then how can I get the tr's id using jquery after clicking Update having id "quick-update-order-product"

```
<tr id="product-id-<?=$product->product->id;?>">            
        <td><span class="product_price_show"></span></td>
        <td><span><?=  $product->product_qty; ?></span></td>
        <td><span><?= $product->product->stock->qty; ?></span></td>
        <td><span><?=  $product->total_price_tax_incl; ?></span></td>
        <td>
            <a class="quick-update-order-product">Update</a>                
        </td>            
</tr>
```

Thanks in advance..  :)

Comment: do you have a click handler... if so checkout [.closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, if this row is repeated you should use a class on the button, not an `id`, as duplicate id properties are invalid.

```
<tr id="product-id-<?=$product->product->id;?>">            
    <td><span class="product_price_show"></span></td>
    <td><span><?=  $product->product_qty; ?></span></td>
    <td><span><?= $product->product->stock->qty; ?></span></td>
    <td><span><?=  $product->total_price_tax_incl; ?></span></td>
    <td>
        <a class="quick-update-order-product">Update</a>                
    </td>            
</tr>
```

Once you've got the class on the button you can use `closest()` to find the `tr`:

```
$('.quick-update-order-product').click(function() {
    var trId = $(this).closest('tr').prop('id');
});
```

Comment: why use prop instead of attr?

Comment: @OliSoproniB. A little late, but this is why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5876747/519413

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
$('td a').click(function(){
  alert($(this).closest('tr').attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this [Closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$('.quick-update-order-product').click(function() {
    var trId = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
});
```